# Opening new tab in internet explorer and getting its source code with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, vba, tabs

Is there a way to open a new tab in an internet explorer window that is already open and get its source code? Most of the information I've found included creating a new Internetexplorer object. The secure webpage I'm trying to access doesn't like it when I open a new instance of internet explorer to open the website. Because of that, I would like to open a new tab on an already open internet explorer window to avoid the security/cookie issues. I am ultimately trying to get the source code of a website and extract hyperlinks from it. Below is what I've come up with so far. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Standard module code, like: Module1.
    Dim ie As Object, objDoc As Object

    Const strURI As String = "http://www.cnn.com"

    ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    ie.Navigate(strURI)

    'Wait for page to load!
    Do
        If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
            ie.Visible = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            Application.DoEvents()
        End If
    Loop

    objDoc = ie.Document

    Dim strMyPage As String
    strMyPage = objDoc.body.innerHTML

    TextBox1.Text = strMyPage

    objDoc = Nothing
    ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler2.com/core/) for this purpose.

In order to get the sourcecode for an open tab, you need to use WM_GETOBJECT to get the IHTMLDocument2 interface of the existing document, then you can enumerate the anchor objects in that document.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249232 shows the general pattern.